# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. useEffect Hook

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, use-effect

I seem to be missing something subtle about avoiding memory leaks. I have read a few posts on how to avoid this with async functions and have tried a few things. All seem to fail. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
    useEffect(() => {
let ignore = false;
if (Platform.OS === "android" && !Constants.isDevice) {
  errorMessage("Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!");
} else {

  // function to get location, weather and aurora info
  const getDataAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      setErrorMessage("Permission to access location was denied");
    }
    if (!ignore) {
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
       // do stuff with the location data, putting it into states
      fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          // do all sorts of stuff with the weather json, putting it into states
        });
      // Fetch the aurora data
      const myUTC = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
      fetch(`http://api.auroras.live/v1/?type=ace&data=bz&tz=${myUTC}&colour=hex`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          // do stuff with the aurora json, put it into states
        });
      setIsLoaded(true); // this is for the activity indicator
    }
  }
  getDataAsync();
  return () => { ignore = true; }
}
}, []);
```

I'm getting the error when deliberately quickly switching out of the screen and back again while the activity indicator is spinning.

Answer (score 0):

Return the cleanup outside of everything! let me know if it works

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false;
  if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
    errorMessage(
      'Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!',
    );
  } else {
    // function to get location, weather and aurora info
    const getDataAsync = async () => {
      let {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMessage('Permission to access location was denied');
      }
      if (!ignore) {
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        // do stuff with the location data, putting it into states
        fetch(
          `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`,
        )
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            // do all sorts of stuff with the weather json, putting it into states
          });
        // Fetch the aurora data
        const myUTC = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        fetch(
          `http://api.auroras.live/v1/?type=ace&data=bz&tz=${myUTC}&colour=hex`,
        )
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            // do stuff with the aurora json, put it into states
          });
        setIsLoaded(true); // this is for the activity indicator
      }
    };
    getDataAsync();
  }
  return () => {
    ignore = true;
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

That was promising, but no, it didn't work. It may have to do with the fact that there are 2 async fetch requests and one "await" location request with each taking a different amount of time.

I am trying with abortController but that isn't working either:

```
      useEffect(() => {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
  if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
    errorMessage(
      'Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!',
    );
  } else {
    // function to get location, weather and aurora info
    const getDataAsync = async () => {
      let {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMessage('Permission to access location was denied');
      }
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({signal: abortController.signal});
        // do stuff with the location data, putting it into states
        fetch(
          `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`, { signal: abortController.signal })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            // do all sorts of stuff with the weather json, putting it into states
          });
        // Fetch the aurora data
        const myUTC = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        fetch(
          `http://api.auroras.live/v1/?type=ace&data=bz&tz=${myUTC}&colour=hex`, { signal: abortController.signal })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            // do stuff with the aurora json, put it into states
          });
        setIsLoaded(true); // this is for the activity indicator
    };
    getDataAsync();
  }
  return () => {
      abortController.abort();
    }
}, []);
```

In addition to the memory leak error in the console, I am also getting:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[AbortError: Aborted]

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
[AbortError: Aborted]
```